# Webcam Light / Torch / Flash C#

Tags: c#, directshow, aforge, flashlight

I'm trying to create a C# console application to take a snapshot with a laptop webcam.
The snapshot itself was no problem, (I'm using AForge for this) but now I want to turn on the flash / torch of the webcam. But I can not find any information how to do this.
Found many discussions for phones / iOs, for C++ and many people wanted to deactivate the "indicator light".
Thought about doing it in C++, because I found informations about that with directshow, but also the information that this is not possible with all webcams.
So I wanted to ask you, if you have any informations if this is not possible with my cam (see name below), or do you have any idea what I can try with C# (maybe AForge)?
AVStream Camera 2500
Windows 10

Thank you in advance,
HerrBrati

Comment: Are you asking about disabling the indicator light that tells you it is recording or the "flash" that brightens the picture when you take a photo? It sounds like your doing a flash, but have you ever seen the camera itself flash? It doesn't look like it does.

Comment: I'm talking about the light / flash that brightens the picture. The camera itself does not flash, but there is (aside from the indicator) a light (a very bright LED) for the camera to get more light. This LED is also used with the software from the cam itslef. (got this with the laptop. lenovo btw)

Comment: I imagine you'll have to drop into interop for this and interface with the C++ code.